# Sending PHP post form and working with Vue.js only for "real-time" field validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vue.js, post

The main idea is to work with vue.js only for "real-time" field validation. But the form will only be sent by PHP via the POST method. The problem that vue.js takes over all form and prevents php from continuing in the process.

My code (one-page) test.php:

```php
<?php
  if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
    //do something
  }
?>

<form method="POST">
  <div id="app">
    <b-container>
      <b-form-group horizontal :label-cols="4" description="Let us know your name." label="Enter your name">
        <b-form-input id="input-live" v-model="name" :state="nameState"
                            aria-describedby="input-live-help input-live-feedback" placeholder="Enter your name" trim>
        </b-form-input>
        <b-form-invalid-feedback id="input-live-feedback">
          Enter at least 3 letters (english only)
        </b-form-invalid-feedback>
      </b-form-group>
    </b-container>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_data_from_url(url) {
    var http_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http_req.open("GET", url, false);
    http_req.send(null);
    return http_req.responseText;
  }
 window.app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     name: ''
   },
   computed: {
     nameState() {
       var url = "core/valid.php?name=" + encodeURIComponent(this.name);
       var data_obj = JSON.parse(get_data_from_url(url));
       return (data_obj['status'] == "success") ? true : false;
     }
   },
   data() {
     return {
       name: ''
     }
   }
});
</script>



<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<!-- Required scripts -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont see any submit event triggered or an action attribute that would redirect to php.

Comment: @MrKhan I don't want any trigger/event. I just want to work with PHP when it comes to submitting the form. If I didn't use vue.js for field validation then it would work fine.

Comment: @MrKhan this PHP code working and its like the one i put bellow the only different is the form validation with Vue.js <?php if(!empty($_POST['name'])){echo 'working';}?><form method="POST"><input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit"></form>

Comment: @Hiws <b-form-input> is the name input and submit stay submit button... I am interesting in Vue.js only for “real-time” field validation... do you have an idea how to use PHP post form and check 'name' input “real-time” field validation?

Comment: I missed the submit button placed outside of the Vue root, so i removed the comment when i noticed it. My bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you don't give your input a `name`. So your if `if(!empty($_POST['name']))` will never do anything.

If you add `name="name"` to your `b-form-input` it should work.

#### Snippet i used to test with locally that works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <?php
  if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "Form submitted";
  }
  ?>

  <form method="POST">
    <div id="app">
      <b-container>
        <b-form-group horizontal :label-cols="4" description="Let us know your name." label="Enter your name">
          <b-form-input name="name" id="input-live" v-model="name" :state="nameState" aria-describedby="input-live-help input-live-feedback" placeholder="Enter your name" trim>
          </b-form-input>
          <b-form-invalid-feedback id="input-live-feedback">
            Enter at least 3 letters (english only)
          </b-form-invalid-feedback>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-container>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <!-- Required scripts -->
  <script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

  <script>
    window.app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      computed: {
        nameState() {
          return this.name.length > 3 ? true : false;
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
          name: ''
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you expect. I created a jsfiddle with your code, but changed two things:

1. You have defined data two times, in different forms, so I removed one of them
2. I have placed the script tags above the vue script tag, as it caused errors. Have you checked your js console?
3. I've put a `return true` in the nameState function

Now it just submits the form to https://google.com

I suspect that something goes wrong in your validation function, and after that it will not submit the form, because something blocked it.

Make sure you inspect your js console, as I believe something goes wrong in your validate call.

https://jsfiddle.net/1tz9wb7e/2/

Comment: Not working at all... no for “real-time” field validation and not for php

Comment: the code in my question is a code of one page only ("test.php") i do not need any action when the post is in the same page..

Comment: So did you actually read my answer? I showed you an example, wherein the form DOES actually send your data to a page and it is not picked up by vue, which is what you requested. Then I made some suggestions to point you in the right direction, as I think something goes wrong inside of the validate method. Pretty rude to -1 it and give such harsh comments, while it seems to me you didn't actually look into it.